# Stretch aside bar to fit the page

Tags: css, screen, sidebar, stretch

I got a little problem with my sidebar with the element . I want to place it on the right side of my page to show my social media profiles. I want this bar to stretch out vertically to fit the screen, not my page. So, I don't want any scrollbar to show.

This is my CSS code that I used for this:

```
html
{
position: relative;
min-height: 100%;
} 

aside
{
width:70px;
position:absolute;
right:0;
bottom:0;
top:151px;
background-color:#5A9AA8;
text-align:center;
display:block;
}
```

It does what I want it to do in Chrome, but when I try this in Internet Explorer, the scrollbar shows and the sidebar doesn't fit to the screen.
Am I doing something wrong, am I using a wrong method or do I need to add something? I thank you in advance.

PS: If you don't know what I want to do, please comment and I will provide you with pictures.

EDIT: I'm new to this site and I can't upload pictures... Don't got enough reputation points.

Comment: Please provide the pictures. It will be easier to answer.

Comment: Apparently you need reputation points for that.. And i'm new to this site :s

Comment: Just upload it elsewhere and provide the links. Try photobucket

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is a picture:

http://s1128.photobucket.com/user/Steveclaes06/media/Probleempj.jpg.html

So the left one is google chrome and the right one is Internet Explorer. The  aside bar on chrome always stays in place how I want it to be and you see that this isn't the case in IE. The scrollbar isn't supposed to be there and the background-color isn't following my content aswell.

Don't pay attention to the text being a little weird, that is my fault, due to bad cutting.